# scala withDegreeOfParallelism

Tags: scala, parallel-processing

Having .NET background I have tried to implement some "extension method" for parallel collections looking like here:

```
  implicit class ParSeqExtensions[T](pc : ParSeq[T]) {
    /** limits the number of threads of parallel collection - the equivalent of C# DegreeOfParallelizm*/
    def withDegreeOfParallelism(numberOfThreads: Int): ParSeq[T] = {
      pc.tasksupport = new ForkJoinTaskSupport(new scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool(numberOfThreads))
      pc
    }
  }
  implicit class ParMapExtensions[K,V](map: ParMap[K,V]) {
    def withDegreeOfParallelism(numberOfThreads: Int): ParMap[K,V] = {
      map.tasksupport = new ForkJoinTaskSupport(new scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool(numberOfThreads))
      map
    }
  }
```

The`taskSupport` is defined in the trait:

```
ParIterableLike[+Long, +Beginner <: Unreadable[TypeParameters]]
```

That's boring to implement the same for each `ParXyz` collection type separate. Is scala so mighty to make it once? How?